# Does the explainability feature support batch processing?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-openscale

I checked the UI dashboard of OpenScale and found I can use transaction ID to generate the explaination. However, is it possible to batch explaining the transactions?

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time, Explanability feature in Watson OpenScale does not support generating an explanations for a batch of transactions.  Generating an explanation is an asynchronous process and for each explanation request we generate a request ID which can be used to check the status/fetch the result of the explanation.

You can always send multiple requests by invoking the REST API once for each transaction.